# Checking a valid input (infinite repetition issue)

Tags: python

I am trying to code a game of mastermind at the moment, the part that I am working on now is checking if the user's input is valid(eg. one of the provided colours). The problem I am having is that it the function I created for this purpose will not exit. Here is the relevant part of my code:

```python3
count = 0
check_bool = True
check_count = 0
colours = ["R","O","Y","G","B","I","V"]
correct = True

def check_invalid():
    global guess
    global check_bool
    global check_count
    while check_bool:
        while check_count < 1:
            if guess[int(check_count)] in colours:
                pass
            elif guess[int(check_count)] not in colours:
                check_count += 1
        if check_count >= 1:
            print("Guess",count + 1,":")
            check = input()
        elif check_count == 0:
            check_guess = False
    return guess




while count <= 9 and correct:
    print("Guess",count + 1,":")
    guess = input()
    if guess in C:
        guide()
        print("Guess",count + 1,":")
        guess = input("...")
    [guess[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(guess), n)]
    guess = (guess.upper())
    check_invalid()
    check(answer,guess)
    count += 1
```

If it was the first guess, I want it to output:

```python3
>>>
Guess 1:
...
```

until a valid input is entered

What it really gives me is:

```python3
>>>
Guess 1:
... #user input here#
Guess 1:
... #user input here#
Guess 1:
... #user input here#
Guess 1:
... #user input here#
```

an infinite amount of times until code is exitted

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: `correct` is not defined for the while loop, and what is `guide()`? There are many missing variables in your example. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Miket25 correct is defined, and Ignore all other `def` functions there, they all work

Answer (score 1):

if the guess is in the list you can straight up return.
also with that code, I'm stuck looping in the pass, it should return guess straight up for it is valid

```
        if guess[int(check_count)] in colours:
            return guess
```

The reason you are looping in the question is that you answer incorrectly but after the question done by the check_invalid, you will input it as check instead of guess and it never passes it back to the check_invalid() function. You need to zero the check_count too so that it doesn't just pass the validation step

```
    if check_count >= 1:
        print("Guess", count + 1, ":")
        guess = input()
        check_count = 0
        check_invalid()
```

After the above edits, it works normally(CHECKED)

Also not the slightest clue why that for loop is there in the

Answer (score 0):

It outputs an infinite amount of time. So that means a while true loop in your code.
This following statement in your code will never be false, so it keeps printing.

```
while check_bool:
```

Comment: What are you implying i need to change here @HugodeHeer

Comment: There are many missing variables in your code, so it is not possible for me to resolve the problem. I can tell you that your code keeps printing because: check_bool = True. I also advise you to use for loops instead of while loops, because for loops are much more easier to read

Comment: none of the other `def`'s do anything outputs anything useful. they are just for checking the guess, and printing the rules